# How to build and use literals as object keys in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a Typescript helper type to improve type safety. I want typescript to "calculate" and check object keys as literals.

Currently I have `Word` and `Card` types, but fields in `Word` type are ugly and not really typechecked.

```js
type Card = {
    word_1: Word
    word_2: Word
}

type Word = {
    // ... other stuff

    in_Cards_as_word_1: Card[]
    in_Cards_as_word_2: Card[]
}
```

EDIT: using `LiteralOf` implementation by @jcalz:

```js
interface TypeMap {
    Card: Card;
    Date: Date;
}
type LiteralOf<T> = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: T extends TypeMap[K] ? K : never }[keyof TypeMap];
```

Is it possible to somehow use typechecked helper `InAs` like below?

```js
type InAs<T extends LiteralOf<T>, F extends keyof T> = `in_${LiteralOf<T>}_as_${F}`

type Word = {
    // ... other stuff

    InAs<Card, 'word_1'>: Card[]
    InAs<Card, 'word_2'>: Card[]
}

const word: Word
// this should be valid, because `InAs` uses `LiteralOf` and 
// something like a literal interpolation under the hood
word.in_Card_as_word_1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] by defining or removing anything whose definition isn't currently present (e.g., `LiteralOf`).  This will allow us to paste your code into our own IDEs and immediately get to work solving the issue you have instead of first trying to reproduce it.  (Note that `T extends LiteralOf<T>` could not possibly be satisfied if `LiteralOf<Card>` is `'Card'`, so you should double check that also.)

Comment: Perhaps [one of these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/w25O4W) does what you want, but I had to make guesses about `LiteralOf` and redefining `InAs`, and I'm not sure how general it needs to be (option 1 is the most general, option 3 is the least).  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, sorry, I did not provide `LiteralOf`, because I was quite sure that my implementation was quite bad/ not optimal and I wanted to focus on the other part of the issue. Your `LiteralOf` implementation is beautiful though! Thanks for that! And oh my god! Your solutions in option2 and option3 are much better then I ever hoped for! These are awesome! Thanks! Option1 is not what I was looking for, but really interesing too!

Comment: So I will write up option 3 as an answer when I get a chance, but it would be nice if you could first either remove `LiteralOf` from the question or define it, so that the answer doesn't have to digress from your question as asked.

Comment: Okay, great! I'll use your implementation if that's ok.

Comment: @jcalz Just a note, I just hit that problem in my own implementation: option1 does not raise an error even if the keys in the model change. Do you have any idea why that's the case?

Comment: Because I didn't bother to try to restrict it, which would only make things more complicated and I didn't know if you wanted that option... which apparently you *don't*, so I'm not inclined to try to work on it if that's okay EDIT maybe [this change](https://tsplay.dev/mAJqQW) would do it.  But I'm only going to write about option 3 in the answer

Comment: @jcalz Yes, sorry, I said earlier that I was not looking for option1, because I have seen that it does not have this restriction and I did not realize my solution does not have either. I see option2 as a "more terse" version of option1 if it is applicable, but when it does not, I have to fallback on an option1-like solution. So in that sense I'd prefer option1 over option2 I have just misunderstood the intention of option1 earlier, sorry.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! Just seen the EDIT. Amazing! Thanks! Any of the options are going to be approved!

Answer (score 1):

The last general way to proceed is to assume that for a given type `T`, we are always going to be iterating over all of its properties, and the property type will be `T[]`:

```
type InAsT<T> = { [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol> as InAs<T, K>]: T[] }

type WordT = {
    //... other stuff
} & InAsT<Card>
/* type WordT = {
    in_Card_as_word_1: Card[];
    in_Card_as_word_2: Card[];
} */
```

Here `InAsT<T>` is using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to convert each key `K` from the keys of `T` into `InAs<T, K>`.

---

Slightly more general is to allow the property value type to be specified as `V` instead of assumed to be `T[]`:

```
type InAsTV<T, V> = { [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol> as InAs<T, K>]: V }

type WordTV = {
    //... other stuff
} & InAsTV<Card, Card[]>
/* type WordTV = {
    in_Card_as_word_1: Card[];
    in_Card_as_word_2: Card[];
} */
```

---

The most general solution I can think of is to allow each property of the output to be specified separately.  There isn't a *great* syntax for this; each property would need a triplet of type `T`, one of its keys `K`, and the intended value type `V` for the resulting property.  So perhaps it should take a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  Like this:

```
type InAsTKV<TKV extends [any, string | number, any] & C,
    C = TKV extends [infer T, any, any] ? [T, keyof T, any] : never> =
    { [U in TKV as InAs<U[0], U[1]>]: U[2] }

type WordTKV = {
    // ... other stuff
} & InAsTKV<
    | [Card, 'word_1', Card[]]
    | [Card, 'word_2', Card[]]
>
/* type WordTKV = {
    in_Card_as_word_1: Card[];
    in_Card_as_word_2: Card[];
} */
```

It's fundamentally the same operation, except that instead of iterating over each key of `T`, we are iterating over each union member of `TKV`, which we split into `T`, `K`, and `V` before outputting as a key value.

I've also made a constraint `C` to ensure that for each member of `TKV`, the `K` element is a key of the `T` element.  It (ab)uses a [generic type argument default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to do this, in order to avoid a circularity warning (otherwise `TKV` is dependent on itself directly in a way the compiler doesn't like).

---

Anyway, it depends on your use case which one of those approaches (or combination of those approaches) you want to employ.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCZQLxQN4Cgq6gdwHtkB9ARgC4oB1YpAFQGkA1HPI0gJituSdYC+WLAEsAdsAgIAZnADG0euAgBZOGExtc8ZFR1IA3FqgAROJKpnJRoaEhQAMiMkI4AGwDy0gDz0AfGiYUADajFDiUADWECCE0lBKkGpgALpU9FAQAB6SYkgAzgnKyaEpUAD8UGFUYhAAblJQAsHRsfGJquopRnbQAJJiAIL5vgA0UABimTkQeYX5wAjiAOZQAD5QYgCuALYARlIB6AAG4iQAJBhOLu5evn4CJHD5FxgTAsfCAPRfUG4Qz2AUGWsyk7iwvSgA2G9HugQwITCEQAolk5G4tkgIN5WnEEuN8iB9oQ3AFnlChiN6ONGH40glgmVbMoaHQMuhsHgoD8AHR8qCEYAAC0aCy20mkWAEUAAZBSYd59H4sF8AFRQSG8Bjw4xnfRPF4cJDkPSIJCMoxcvVmg0kI0kbiwM0WqVQVVfb6-HbEaAg2quNwQlnQ-L0ZhjKDMI5BULhMRQVHozHY3HtAlEvYksmFEMR2n05hNIP2LVhnVc3n8wUihBQMUS11ykNhxVm8b6RnKtUalmlwsc3ViEj6552ugmp3IF1Wocjw3jx0d7qu92eqDehC+0EB4v9Sn8Xwsaa5AohOBiEAExYrdabXYHBDjc8gMpymCjYwwQL8Y+zU-BcRpEaakoGfJ8LzKSpghA1N8VAiCoBqepDjQYwEWCABVOMEiPclcww4IAAYUnGAiyBSOkqAIzgmV3Vk+CPAcK1+PkeQFYVRWAcVJWlJt9xYbxjA2YJ9HGABye0yDE9tnRSFIhJCUSoAkhdpMnc05KwLt1U1NlGM0GdhxtUdJNNKdl0Mucxy4MyNJsN0viAA)